# How to Setup Triple Monitors with Kali Linux?

Tags: gnome, kali-linux, graphics, multi-monitor

I installed Kali Linux 2 on my laptop and need to configure a triple monitor setup with it.
At the moment, I have a Belkin Dual DVI docking station and a Startech DVI to USB 3 converter. On Windows 7, I had two of my monitors use DVI to connect to the Docking station and the third monitor used a USB 3 port on the Docking station. Here is a picture of my setup on Windows 7 which worked perfectly okay:

[image]

An here is a picture of my Docking station:
[image]

Here is a link if you want to know more about the Belkin docking station:
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Belkin-B2B122-BLK-Display-Docking-Ultrabooks/dp/B00JG0ZG8Q

Now, when I launch Kali 2 and connect my Belkin Docking station, one of my screens turn green but the other 2 remain off:

[image]

Running `lsusb` **before** connecting the docking station looks like this:

```
root@kali:~# lsusb 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:9301 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Running `lsusb` while the docking station is connected shows the following:

```
root@kali:~# lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:9301 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 17e9:4333 DisplayLink 
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 17e9:028f DisplayLink 
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 1bcf:0053 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here is my video card information:

```
root@kali:~# lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Here is the result of `xrandr` command:

```
root@kali:~# xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
   1366x768      59.99*+  40.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       59.94  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

After some testing I found that my mouse and keyboard are recognized through the Docking Station, however, for some reason the DVI's are not. looking at the result of `lsusb` I noticed that DisplayLink maybe the manufacturer and driver so I did some googling and found that they support Ubuntu but not Debian. Digging a bit deeper, found a script on [Github](https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian/blob/master/displaylink-debian.sh) that said it will install DisplayLink drivers for Debian so I used it, however, it said my platform is not supported!

```
root@kali:~/Downloads# ./displaylink-deb.sh 

DisplayLink driver for Debian GNU/Linux

[I]nstall
[U]ninstall
Select a key: [i/u]: i
Checking dependencies...
unzip is installed
linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-amd64 is installed
dkms is installed
lsb-release is installed

------------------------------------------------------

Unsuported platform: Kali kali-rolling

This tool is Open Source and feel free to extend it
GitHub repo: https://goo.gl/6soXDE

------------------------------------------------------

root@kali:~/Downloads#
```

It may also be worth mentioning that when I open Kali from VMWare Workstation on Windows 7 I'm able to use all 3 monitors:

[image]
Any advice is really appreciated.

Comment: Well, the first recommendation is to try whatever tools you have available. Since you haven't told us what desktop environment you use, we can't know what those are. That said, the `xrandr` output only shows one screen so I'm guessing the docking station isn't recognized correctly. This isn't surprising, it probably comes with some windows-only driver. I recommend you first try and figure out how to get the docking station working. Perhaps post a new question giving the details of the station.

Comment: My Desktop Environment is GNOME. Here is more detail about the Belkin Docking station: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Belkin-B2B122-BLK-Display-Docking-Ultrabooks/dp/B00JG0ZG8Q

Comment: MANY docking stations just do not work with Linux. It's a few years old but look at https://www.change.org/p/displaylink-support-linux-with-dl-3000-series-chips

Answer (score 1):

You could use this modified driver from github.
https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian

The script needs a minor modification for **Kali-rolling**.

1. Open the shell script named "displaylink-debian.sh" with any text editor.
2. Check line 90 and replace "Debian" with "Kali" *elif [ "$lsb" == "Kali" ];*
3. Check line 92 and replace "sid" with "kali-rolling" *[ $codename == "kali-rolling" ];*
4. Save and run script as superuser.

**5. Be sure to follow the post-installation guide**.

Answer (score 0):

Displaylink has recently updated their driver. Screen is a lot less lagging.

**Getting unsatisfied dependencies while headers are installed?
Download the driver from DisplayLinks official page and use this fix:**

> It’s time to dissect the displaylink download. The downloaded archive “DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for Ubuntu 1.2.zip” contains the binary “displaylink-driver-1.2.58.run”. This in turn is itself an archive which contains the install script that checks for the kernel headers. With ./displaylink-driver-1.2.58.run --help you can find out that with ./displaylink-driver-1.2.58.run --keep --noexec --target displaylink-driver-1.2.58 the install scripts will be extracted to the subdirectory displaylink-driver-1.2.58/ without executing the script. Now you can modify the install script displaylink-driver-1.2.58/displaylink-installer.sh. In the function “check_requirements()” you see, that the script checks for the existence of the file /lib/modules/4.6.0-1-amd64/build/Kconfig. If it doesn’t exist, it spits out “Unsatisfied dependencies. Missing component: Linux headers for running kernel, 4.6.0-1-amd64”. I simply commented out this line as I know, I have the kernel headers installed. Now I can run the install script manually with ./displaylink-installer.sh install.

**Source:** https://adangel.org/2016/09/26/display-link-dell-intel-debian/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I used:

```
sudo xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0
```

Try it!